# Does it count towards an extraction if you miss extraction?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In Mass Effect 3 there are challenges that want you to extract 10 times with a certain character or 15 times on a specific map. If you die (so really die, not just downed and revived) or miss the extraction (by not standing in the blue circle when countdown ends), does it still count towards these challenges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do not have to extract yourself, as long as someone else of the team does extract (so the mission should not fail). I know this, because I got a progress banner ("6/10 extractions") in the lower right of the screen after extraction, where I died. This banner is only showed when there is an advancement.

Comment: Just to make it clear, at least 1 person **has** to be in the circle at the end. If no one is, then it's a failure and doesn't count.